# tinder style ecommerce app with random product search generator

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, e-commerce

I am currently developing a website for a final year project and i am a little stuck on which code to develop it with or 3rd party system.

The website will need:

a log in/ register

enable users upload items to sell into database

have a way to narrow down database with a miniature preferences form( refined search).

it will then display items which fit the preferences one by one in random order with a next button which will randomize the items in the preferences but will remove the (current) viewed item from the random selection.

I have though to used HTML, CSS and Javascript/ Ajax / jquery with Some php and possibly xml/Mysql.

If anybody knows a better way to do it or a third party like wordpress or shopify. please help.

I mainly need help with the database, the preferences/ refine search and the randomization.

Answer (score 0):

Use what ever you are most comfortable with, look in to frameworks like Laravel